# Lowercase app routing

Tags: python, routes, flask

```
@app.route("/<requested_username>/<requested_team>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

^How do I make this so that no matter what is entered - it still goes to the correct url

For example:

```
/jose/SWaGGer   #should work
/jOse/swagger   #should work
/josE/Swagger   #should work
etc.
```

Oh, and I am using Python/Flask by the way - and nope I did not find an explanation for this in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view method call `lower()` on your strings before working with them. If you do this, they will always be stored and used lower case.

E.g.:

```
@app.route('/user/<requested_username>/<requested_team>')
def thing(requested_username, requested_team):
    requested_team = requested_team.lower()
    requested_username = requested_username.lower()

    ... then continue with the view
```

You should then always store your strings in lower case in your database, so call `lower` before saving them.

Comment: But I want my team name to be stored however the user originally wanted it to look like. For example, shouldn't it be stored as Argonauts rather than argonauts

Comment: Depending on your database you may be able to do case-insensitive comparison. Postgres? Mysql?

Comment: This should give you some pointers. http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-php/2003-05/msg00045.php